# OOP PHP authentication and authorization to projects

Tags: php, authentication, authorization

Now i want to implement authorization to the functions to my project but i do not know where to begin for oop php project

or the best approach to design **user roles** and giving user privileges or authority to **READ**,**EDIT**,**UPDATE** and **DELETE** according to their **role** (or to access part of file depending on the role) in **PHP** and **mysql**

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends what the project is and the structure of it but in general yes, you would assign roles to a user and then limit access to page elements AND methods depending on the role.

So in my project I have user roles:

1 - Admin

2 - Editor

3 - Viewer

I set the user role at login through a **$_SESSION['userRole']** variable.

I may have a function as follows:

```
public function editPost() {
    if($_SESSION['userRole']<3) {
        // edit post code here
    } else {
        echo "You don't have permission to edit posts";
    }
}
```